# pytest fast pass

Tags: python, unit-testing

Is there a method which I can call which will immediately mark a test as passed?

With NUnit you call Asset.Pass(), However I have not been able to find a similar method.

For some context, I am trying to assert that a method was called.

```
    def test_calls_my_method(self):
        # can't assign a variable from inside lambda so we will
        # modify this object
        call_count = []

        mock = MyMock()

        mock.method = lambda : call_count.append(True)

        # Edit, this is what I really want to do
        #mock.method = lamda : self.assertPass()


        to_test = ClassToTest()
        to_test.foo = mock

        # Act

        # ...Snip...


        self.assertTrue(len(call_count) > 0) # was method called by to_test

        #self.assertFail ()
```

Comment: You don't need to implement mock objects yourself. [`mock.Mock`](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/index.html#quick-guide) already has [`call_count`](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/mock.html#mock.Mock.call_count) attribute. [In Python 3.3+ the module is in the Python standard library as `unittest.mock`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0417/).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian +1, didn't even think about a mock framework with python. mock.method.assert_called was what I was after.